# Anylogic: limiting used resources

Tags: anylogic

I am currently modelling the entire production process of a company with limited human resources.

Part of the model is visualized here:

[image: Part of the model]

**The Model**: In the example there are multiple blocks but the focus for me is on the resource using blocks. The assemblers use 2 resources, the service, seize and rackstore blocks use 1 resource each. As you can imagine they are all fully utilized as I only have a resourcepool of 6 people (and there are more processes beyond this)

**Question**: Because of this full utilization my entire process is blocked because there are no free resources. Therefore I would like to ask if it would be possible for me to limit e.g. the blue part of the example flow to 3 employees using the same resourcepool? That way I can set priorities between the processes and make the process work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hold blocks to stop products to flow if the used resources are equal to 3
[image: structure of model]

The code:
On enter delay (when the resource is seized)

```
resourcesInAssembler++;
if(resourcesInAssembler==3){
    hold2.block();
    hold1.block();
    hold.block();
}
```

On exit (when the resource is released)

```
resourcesInAssembler--;
hold.unblock();
hold1.unblock();
hold2.unblock();
```

Comment: You count agents with this according to my model, as you count the amount of agents, originating from the source block, which enter the assembler. Is it not possible to count the amount of resources used with the variable and remove the resourcesInAssembler++; in your code?

Comment: you are wrong, I'm not counting the agents, i'm counting the resources... so your question doesn't make sense